# How to print specific elements from an array of string, ignoring int and special characters at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, input, element

Well, hello

What I want to do is basically.

This is the input in the string array using jTextArea1.

```
==================
Sarah ID 1059
Jones ID 2095
Chris ID 5059
Samantha ID 3506
================
```

I want to manipulate the string array elements and print them in this way in jTextArea2.

```
=================
Welcome Sarah ID "1059" Sarah GoodBye
Welcome Jones ID "2095" Jones GoodBye
Welcome Chris ID "5059" Chris GoodBye
Welcome Samantha ID "3506" Samantha GoodBye
=================
```

This is the code I have prepared so far with the help of others, but I am stuck on the part where I want to print only specific elements (in my case i want only the name to be printed) while ignoring integer and special characters in the elements from being printed at the same time.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String[] names = jTextArea1.getText().split("\\.");
    String text = "";
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        text += "welcome " + names[i] 
            + "Don't know what will come here"+"GoodBye";
    }
    jTextArea2.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Hint: you want to turn back to your question and drop all those HTML tags. In other words: don't assume that certain input is requested; instead: take the time to turn to the help center and **understand** what is possible. I just tried to make your source code more readable, but doesn't work out; simply because your text is way to HTMLish

Comment: Side note on code quality: don't do that: do not "compute" everything in one place. Write a method that splits your strings, and gives you the elements your are looking for. Instead of directly manipulating the string coming back form the textfield. What happens for example, if the text field has slightly wrong entries?!

Comment: Your code is not displaying properly.

Comment: In what cases do you only want specifics?

Comment: By specific elements i think i said it wrong, The input is Sarah ID "1059" Once submit button is clicked I want the output like this
Welcome Sarah ID "1059" Sarah GoodBye

I want to fetch name Sarah only from the element[0] suppose to be displayed before GoodBye. Only the name has to be fetched, and not the Numbers or any special characters like " ".

Answer (score 0):

if "Sarah ID 1059" is the input string.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String names[] = jTextArea1.getText().split(" ");
    String text = "";
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        text += "welcome " + names[0] + "ID" + names[2] + 
                 names[0] + "GoodBye";
    }
    jTextArea2.setText(text);
}
```